# READ ERROR when deploying Polymer web app onto Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-hosting

I'm trying out Polymer web components for the first time and everything is working perfectly fine using Brackets Live Preview.

But when I try to deploy the app using Firebase hosting I get a READ ERROR.

> READ ERROR - Could not read directory. Remove symbolic links / shortcuts and try again.

I updated firebase-tools but still get the same error.

I've spent so many hours going through tech forums hoping I'd find somebody having the same issue but unsuccessful.

Any information regarding my inquiry is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your app's directory contains a shortcut or a symbolic link. You need to replace that with the actual content before firebase-tools can upload the site. Once you've removed the shortcut `firebase deploy` should work as expected